# Android Studio : Failed to create JVM error code : -1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

Please dont mark it as duplicate.

I did make changes as per other answers available when error code was -4.
Now it is showing error code : -1.

Kindly give me some direction.

here is my studio.exe.vmoptions file

```
 server
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Had the same problem, this was my solution:

1. go to `C:\Users\ *username* \\.androidStudio\` (your path might be a bit different, but make sure to go the **local** version of Android Studio, **not** the general version (that lives in the *Program Files* directory)),
2. find the `studio.exe.vmoptions` (or `studio64.exe.vmoptions`) file and delete it.
3. try to open Android Studio again.

Comment: Didn't know about this local version, worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day!

Comment: go to C:\Users\ *username* \androidStudio{Version}\config\  , find the studio64.exe.vmoptions or studio.exe.vmoptions , and delete it.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me, like said Aryeh in above answer.

1. I opened the directory `C:\Users\(myself)\.AndroidStudio2.2` and deleted the file `studio64.exe.vmoptions` ( I did a copy before, with prefix OLD_, using a text editor ),
2. Then launch Android Studio,
3. Go to AS menu  "Help > Edit Custom VM Options ..." (this makes a new file "studio64.exe.vmoptions" that you can edit).

Answer (score 0):

Go in C drive and go to user ex: "C:\Users\vijay" and shift + delete all android and android studio folders. Then click and open Android studio.
that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.
If you have done some changes in the local files namely studio.exe.vmoptions or studio64.exe.vmoptions using wordpad (which i had done after reading some other solutions on google but they didn't worked for me ), then first undo those changes.

Comment: For proper clarification, please specify the changes you had made or provide the references of the sources you referred to.

Answer (score 0):

And for those who just edited their `.vmoptions` and messed it up, this is where that file is (according to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)):

> Both configuration files are stored in the configuration folder for
>   Android Studio. The name of the folder depends on your Studio version.
>   For example, Android Studio 3.3 has the folder name AndroidStudio3.3.
>   The location of this folder depends on your operating system:
>
> ```
> Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.CONFIGURATION_FOLDER
> macOS: ~/Library/Preferences/CONFIGURATION_FOLDER
> Linux: ~/.CONFIGURATION_FOLDER
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using the Android studio version 4, can find the studio64.exe.vmoptions in the following path:  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

as mentioned here in the official documentation of Android: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config